# Unicode fonts in terminal

Tags: fonts, redhat-enterprise-linux, unicode

How can I get unicode fonts in my terminal?  Is there a package I could `yum install` to see more characters?

I already have some of them working fine, e.g. 0x2603 [snowman](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2603/index.htm) works, but others just give me boring old boxes for example 0x1f4a9 which should be a [pile of poop](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F4A9/browsertest.htm).

[image]

I'm using RHEL 7.1 and gnome-terminal 3.8.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem I simply didn't have fonts installed.  I followed one of the links in Thomas Dickey's answer and installed [NotoEmoji-Regular.ttf](https://github.com/googlei18n/noto-emoji/blob/master/fonts/NotoEmoji-Regular.ttf?raw=true).  Now I can see poop.  Hooray!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your version of gnome-terminal might be too old to handle the [Emoji](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/lynx-dev/2015-07/msg00007.html).  Someone reported an [issue with Lynx](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=790847) which I found was actually a problem with the older versions of gnome-terminal.

Comment: The terminal was not too old, but that emoji linked helped find a solution.  +1 for putting me on the right track !